# Distribution of N objects into C bins that are then sorted?

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, expected-value, convergence

Let's say we have $C$ bins and $N$ indistinguishable objects. For each object we choose one bin at random where each bin is equally likely (with probability $1/C$). Let $B_k$ be the number of objects in the $k$-th bin after all objects have been distributed. It seems that all $B_k$ individually must be Bernoulli-distributed, but if you consider $B = (B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_C)$ as a multivariate random variable, then I think we have a multinomial distribution, that is

$$P(B = \vec t) = \begin{cases} \binom{N}{t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_N} \frac{1}{C^N} & \text{ if } \sum_k t_k = N \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise } \end{cases}$$

Now consider a new random variable $G = sort(B)$, which means for every $G$ that has a positive probability we have $G_1 \leq G_2 \leq \ldots \leq G_C$ (and obviously $\sum_i G_i = N$).

Is it possible to find the distribution of $G$ explicitly? Or at least an explicit formula for the expectation $E[G]$?

The reason I'm asking is that it seems that (if you choose $C$ and $N$ large enough) the distribution will converge to some curve. Here is a plot of a sample that was computed with $C=100$ and $N=10000$ and you can already see a nice reverse-s shaped curve to which this distribution seems to converge to. I'd like to find out whether this is actually the case and if possible find a formula for this curve (by computing $E[G]$).
[image]

Just for reference, here is the snipped used to generate this plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
C=100
N=10000
a = np.random.random(N)
a = np.round(a*C)
b = plt.hist(a, bins=C)
c = b[0]
c.sort()
plt.clf()
plt.bar(list(range(1,C+1)), c)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The multinomial distribution can be approximated by independent binomial distributions, and when the numbers are large those will be approximately normal distributed variables (with mean $N/C$ and variance $N/C (1-1/C)$).

Then the value of $B_i$ will be approximately the $i/N$-th quantile of that normal distribution. (more precisely it will follow some [joint order statistic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Probabilistic_analysis), but with growing numbers the approximation becomes better)

So you are looking at something that resembles the quantile function of the normal distribution.